# Android USB modem get instantly disconnected

Tags: network-manager, android, usb-modem

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 install and LG G3 stylus phone, which I use as a USB modem(it works on windows well)
When i switch it to usb modem mode it works for 10-20 seconds, and than connection dissapears, seems that network manager crashes
What can be done?

Comment: Doesn't it have the usual USB tethering function? Is that what you mean by "usb modem"?